# Shell script : install missing software if command not found

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

to give some context I am working in a Amazon ec2 linux environment that is running docker and within a docker-container is hosting Jenkins. In my Jenkins pipeline I am able to write shell scripts but I am new to scripting and despite my efforts looking for solutions, I've hit a hard block.

*All I am attempting to do in my script, is verify that my software is installed (both cf-cli and angular-cli) and if they are not, then install them*. 
I've been playing around before using actual install commands but here is my approach, hopefully this is somewhat common industry practice but I am not sure:

**if** [ 'cf version' does **not** fail due to command not found ] 
**then** do nothing since already installed 
**else** install cf

The following is my current script and it keeps exiting execution in my first if statement because the cf command is not found. This is exactly what I'm trying to use for the if statement flow but I'm not sure how. Something else I noticed is that in this container I **DO** have angular installed already and I do get a version output from the 'ng version' command but the script would **always** echo that it was adding angular to my system as if the second if statement was false. If there is anyone that can help guide me, I appreciate you.

```
sh '''
    echo 'Verifying cf-cli installation'
    if [ "cf version" -ne 127 ]
    then
        echo 'cf-cli must be installed. Do nothing'
    else
        echo 'Adding the Cloud Foundry to your system...'
    fi

    ANGULAR_VERSION=$(ng version 2>&1)
    if [ $ANGULAR_VERSION ]
    then
        echo 'angular must be installed. do nothing'
    else
        echo 'Adding angular to your system...'
    fi
    '''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scripts-common](https://gitlab.com/bertrand-benoit/scripts-common) to reach your need.

To check if something is installed, you just need to check it like that:

```sh
checkBin cf-cli || errorMessage "This tool requires cf-cli. Install it please, and then run this tool again."
```

If you want to manage automatically the installation, you can do:

```sh
if ! checkBin cf-cli; then
  # Instructions to install it
fi
```